# Concatenating CHAR(10) in Fomula ignores line break

Tags: excel-formula

quick question:

A Cell with formula

```
="a" & CHAR(10) & "b"
```

will just show `ab` (single line in cell).
Why does it not show:

`a
b`

(2 lines in cell)?

My understanding is, that CHAR(10) is the "intra-cell-new-line character" (on Windows at least).
What am I missing?

I'm using Office 365 ProPlus on Win10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the cell with `WRAP` on                        :

[image]

*(sadly, a formula can not format a cell automatically to achieve this)*